# Graph database (neo4j) vs relational database. Need help in design

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I have to work with an open source project ([biojava](http://biojava.org/wiki/Main_Page)), but I'm not satisfied with some performance, and I'd like to spend some time to improve it.

For example, I have a text database coded in this way:

```
chrX    Cufflinks   exon    65175856    65175971    .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_002576"; transcript_id "TCONS_00004217"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "RP6-159A1.2"; oId "CUFF.3698.1"; nearest_ref "ENST00000456392"; class_code "p"; tss_id "TSS3873";    
chrX    Cufflinks   exon    128986006   128986088   .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_002577"; transcript_id "TCONS_00004218"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.3750.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS3874";
```

Not every field is mandatory, each `gene_id` may be associated to multiple `transcript_id` (1..n), and each `transcript_id` has 1 or more `exon`.

The library behavior is to load the entire text file in an `ArrayList`, and for each search al the list must be iterated. This works good with small lists, but in my case I have 10^10 queries with a really large list, and it takes a couple of days in a good computer.

Would Neo4j be a good choice? What would be a good way to implement it? For example, is it bad to create a String only entity, and make relationships between them? Or is it better to use Hsqldb with a single table?

Please note I don't need persistence, but speed and synchronization is mandatory.

EDIT: if you want, you can have a look at the project [here](https://github.com/biojava/biojava/tree/master/biojava3-genome/src/main/java/org/biojava3/genome/parsers/gff).

Comment: (You should tag your question with "neo4j" and "hsqldb", your question will have a better visibility)

Answer (score 0):

If the speed in critical, as your data schema seems "simple", you can do a "by hand" solution. If development time in more important then "absolute speed", an in-memory RDBMS is a good option.
If persistence is not needed, I would avoid neo4j as it was more designed for persistence and your data seems to be more "relational" then "complex graph"

If speed is critical and them you don't take a solution like Hsqldb, the idea would be to fill 3 kind of objects (gene, transcript, exon), and use hashmaps to index them.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4J works well when you want to find needles in haystacks, i.e. when you have a large dataset, but when you run queries, you are only interested querying for a small amount of the data. For example, if you had a graph like:

```
(gene) -> (transcript) -> (exon)
```

then Neo4J would be good at running queries such as "Starting with gene XLOC_002576, give me all it's transcripts and give me all the other genes also related to those transcripts". (I have no idea what transcripts and exons are, so that query probably doesn't make sense, but you get the idea).

If you are not looking for the needle in the haystack, and instead are processing the whole dataset for every query, then Neo4J is unlikely to be the tool for the job. If the datasets are really huge (as in hundreds of Gigabytes) are you are reducing the whole data set down to a small answer and you don't mind distributing the processing across several machines, then maybe using [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) map reduce and uploading you large text files to HDFS could be an option.

If you provide a little more information about your query profile, it would help in providing a better answer. i.e. what are you doing to the data? what do you mean by 'search'?